# Rounded number issue

Tags: rounding, hana, sap-erp

While using SAP HANA, there is an issue I cannot understand.

I have a field "NET_VALUE" which is equal, in ECC, to 193.40 for example. I pick this column in SAP HANA and the result is still 193.40.

But when I create a calculated column, which expression is

```
IF(A != 0, "NET_VALUE"/B, "NET_VALUE") // in this case A is always equal to 0
```

I get the result 193,39

What I think is that ECC and HANA automatically round the value of NET_VALUE (not for the calculated column) in the way it is display, but not affect the "real" value of NET_VALUE; I do not know how to verify this...

Have you ever encountered this phenomenon and/or do you know what could it be due to?

Comment: Finally, I found that passing number to decimal give the same result as in ECC (so I do not think it is the real value but in a certain way this is a solution)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example, my best bet is that you are facing the effects of floating point number operations here. 
You might want to check and see if you cannot convert the numbers to fixed point decimals before any calculation.